# MySQL 5.5 to 5.7 - losing connections when running older VB app

Tags: mysql, linux, vb6, odbc

Users getting lost connections while using an older VB application (ODBC 3.51).

I've tweaked max_allowed_packet.  I've increased connect_timeout, net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout, doubling or more.  I have max_connections set to 1000.

Oddly, it seems to happen in waves.  I see them through the day, but then we'll get five or more all at once (approx. 90 users).

I see no errors in error.log, no warnings.  Error log level is 3.  Log warnings is 2.  I am not seeing where a higher value would do anything for me.

This worked just fine in 5.5, but 5.7 seems to have introduced something that is causing us issues.  Ubuntu 18.04 if it matters.

These are MyISAM tables, not InnoDB.

The errors we see normally: 'SQL Retry failed 4 times' or 'Not allowed when the object is closed.'

```
mysqld.cnf:
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 128M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
secure_file_priv="/"
connect_timeout=60
skip_name_resolve=ON
net_read_timeout=60
net_write_timeout=120
sql_mode=
```

I'm sorry, I've searched all through and found nothing that matches my situation.  Any assistance is of course appreciated.

Comment: increasa the timeout further 600 or 1200, also scheck the slwo qury log, if always the same query need to long

Comment: Timeout increase didn't help, and the slow query log has no entries.  I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: slow query log doesn't seem to be enabled,, so do that. and how much increased 300000?

Comment: I've tried 60, 360, 28800 - all the same response.  Slow query log is enabled, just after I had posted that cnf file.

Comment: i see only one option to change the time out in vb https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-querytimeout-property-dao, it doesn't seem to be a mysql problem.